# How to create live activity object in tests? It returns error ActivityKit.ActivityAuthorizationError.unsupportedTarget

Tags: ios, swift, widgetliveactivity, activitykit

When I'm trying to mock a Live Activity object in unit tests, it always returns error `ActivityKit.ActivityAuthorizationError.unsupportedTarget` but the ActivityKit is Swift native framework. The main app is working as expected, live activities are displayed without issues.

Here is example when I let it crash on purpose during test setup phase.
The error message is:
`Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: ActivityKit.ActivityAuthorizationError.unsupportedTarget`

[image]

When I tried making `ActivityKit` testable, the error message is: `Module 'ActivityKit' was not compiled for testing`

[image]

Any idea how to fix it?